# TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED event is not getting received by accessibility service if specific packages are added in its configuration xml

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

I am having issue receiving notification change event using accessibility service in specifically Android 9 devices. It is properly working in below Android 9 devices.

Comment: Did you got the solution for that, i am also stuck in this problem????

Comment: @YongTao Ye follow the instructions mentioned by him. It fixes the issue. I have done the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have met the same question, and I solved it by delete the `android:packageNames="your packageName"` in accessibility service config xml. There are some changes in the Android 9.0 that cause the notification event can't be received by `onAccessibilityEvent` directly. The other way to solve it by using NotificationListenerService instead of AccessibilityService in Android 9.0.